# Cannot get tabbed UI to work with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have this simple [tabbed UI](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/9009/) created with knockout, but cannot get it to work.

```
<div>   
    <div data-bind="foreach:editors">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text:$data,click:$parent.selectEditor" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach:editors">
        <h4 data-bind="text:$data,visible:$parent.isVisible" />
    </div>
</div>


 var vm = {
     editors: ko.observableArray(['Editor1','Editor2']),
     selectedEditor: ko.observable('Editor1'),
     isVisible: function(editor){
         return selectedEditor() == editor;
     }
 };

 vm.selectEditor = function(editor){
     vm.selectedEditor(editor);
 };

 ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

When the links are clicked nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to close `<a>` tag, or it gives exeption in chrome,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the HTML and View Model:

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/LkqTU/9013/

```
<div>   
    <div data-bind="foreach:editors">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text:$data,click:$root.selectEditor"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="text: selectedEditor">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to list all editor and then hide/show based on selected. The observable array must be array of objects (can not be strings), with isVisible obesrvable property:

```
editors: ko.observableArray([{
        name: 'Editor1'
        isVisible: ko.observable(false)
    }, {
        name: 'Editor2'
        isVisible: ko.observable(false)
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it a bit like this:

```
<div>   
    <div data-bind="foreach:editors">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text:$data,click:$root.selectedEditor"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach:editors">
        <h4 data-bind="text:$data,visible:$root.selectedEditor() == $data" />
    </div>
</div>

 var vm = {
     editors: ko.observableArray(['Editor1','Editor2']),
     selectedEditor: ko.observable('Editor1')
 };

 ko.applyBindings(vm)
```